# How to restart SoapUI's JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, soapui

I am currently testing some changes to SoapUI JRE's settings on 'Preferences -> SSL' tab and to apply changes I close and then open again a SoapUI instance.
(Windows 10; SoapUI 5.3.0)

Is there a better (smarter) way of restarting SoapUI's JVM?
Preferably the one without closing the instance.

Comment: Nope. You have to close the GUI instance and start it again.

Answer (score 0):

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818212/how-to-restart-soapuis-jvm#comment78594482_45818212) answers the question:

> You have to close the GUI instance and start it again.